# paramiko - login to a host not requiring a password

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

How can I login to a ssh-server, if this ssh server does not demand a password.

On the (here) powershell the following works fine:

```bash
ssh root@myMachine
root@myMachine$:
```

no password asked, just simple login and hello from the machine.

My python code looks like this:

```py
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
print("connecting...")
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", port=XX)

# Error:
# >       raise SSHException("No authentication methods available")
# E       paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available
```

The error arises from a case selection in `paramiko/client.py` which simply does not have the case where no password is provided and it works like it. If I provide a password, the authentication fails.

**How can I tell paramiko to just login and don't bother for the password?**

ok... figured something out... You can go via Transport.

```py
t = paramiko.Transport(("localhost", 2022))
t.connect()
t.auth_none("root")
x = t.open_session()
noting_returned = x.exec_command("touch /tmp/huhu.txt")
```

How ever, the channell closes after each command and I can't see a way in how to retrieve the stdout/error/returnvalue etc.

- **Can I use the existing transport as source for an SSHClient?**
- **Would this be the intended way to go?**

Answer (score 0):

*The following solution is a wrap up from the two sources provided by [@Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) and the creators of the linked knowledge.*

**How can I tell paramiko to just login and don't bother for the password?**

- on a streight forward way - no!
- some fiddeling required

  - [catch exception, alter transport (example below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749222/paramiko-authentication-to-server-with-no-password-fails)

[The low level stuff does not return the std out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989743/providing-input-to-command-su-executed-using-python-paramiko-transport-class-d), only upper function does after performing some io's.

```py
import paramiko

    host = "localhost"
    port = 2022
    username = "root"
    password = None

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    # Workaround for no authentication:
    # https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/890#issuecomment-906893725
    try:
        client.connect(host, port=port, username=username, password=password)
    # except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
        if not password:
            client.get_transport().auth_none(username)
        else:
            raise e

    # Now we can interact with the client as usual
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls /")
    lines = stdout.readlines()
    print(lines)
```